# Rename only the first part of a list of files (Windows 8.1 via cmd or Git Bash)

Tags: command-line, bash, windows-8.1, file-management, batch-rename

I need to rename a batch of files (*in W8.1 using cmd or Git Bash terminal*) from:

```
"Cymatics - Oracle 808 1 - C.wav"  
"Cymatics - Oracle 808 2 - C#.wav"
"Cymatics - Oracle 808 3 - D.wav"  
"Cymatics - Oracle 808 4 - D#.wav"
"Cymatics - Oracle 808 5 - D#.wav"
```

The expected results:

```
"Oracle 808 1 - C.wav" 
"Oracle 808 2 - C#.wav" 
"Oracle 808 3 - D.wav" 
"Oracle 808 4 - D#.wav" 
"Oracle 808 5 - D#.wav"
```

Thanks In Advance!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `for /f` loop to do this:

```bat
@echo off

for %%i in (*.wav) do set "_name=%%~nxi" && (
cmd/v/c "ren "%%~fi" "!_name:Cymatics - =!"")
```

**1)** Use `for` to get one by one `file.wav`

```bat
for %%i in (*.wav)
```

**2)** Set `_n` to file name in loop by `%%~n`

```bat
)do set "_n=%%~nxi"
```

**4)** With `cmd/v/c`, execute the command `ren` passing the full path of the loop variable `"%%~fi"` and defining the destination name by removing the string `Cymatics -` from variable `!_n!` using substring `!_n: Cymatics - =[nothing]!`

```bat
set "_n=%%~nxi" && cmd/v/c "ren "%%~fi" "!_n: Cymatics - =!""
```

- Some further reading:

  [√] **[Substring in batch](https://www.dostips.com/DtTipsStringManipulation.php)**

Answer (score 0):

With Git bash.

```
for f in *.wav; do echo mv -v "$f" "${f#*- }"; done
```

- If you think the output is ok, remove the `echo` to actually rename the files
- A word of advice, make a backup of all the things you're editing.